# Dynamic if then statements for simple arithmetic and resetting a counter

Tags: c, refactoring

I write a lot of code like this

```
int x = 0;

//in some loop
x++;
if (x > 10) {
  x = 0;
  //call some function
}
```

How could I extract this into a function, or a macro, where I can combine the decrementing (or incrementing), the value to exceed (or go under), the reset value (0 in this case) and the function call?

EDIT:

I'd love to do something like (pseudocode)

`cycle_counter(x, ++, <10, 0, myfunc);`

Comment: Explain the protoype of the function **myfunc** in the pseudocode provided above ?

Comment: Say it's a void function

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SATURATE_ADD(x, max, inc, reset) ((x) = (x) > (max) ? (reset) : (x) + (inc))
```

and in your example:

```
int x = 0;

SATURATE_ADD(x, 10, 1, 0);
```

And if you want to call some function, just add a function parameter that you will call in your macro.

Comment: I'm testing this, looks like it should work. When this code is compiled, won't it just replace SATURATE_ADD with the following? Would it be cleaner or possible to use integer pointers?

Comment: The macro will be replaced with the assignment by the preprocessor with a simple text substitution. You can use pointers if you want but I don't think it will add anything in readability.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of the function call?

Comment: `#define SATURATE_ADD(x, max, inc, reset, foo) (((x) = (x) > (max) ? (reset) : (x) + (inc)), foo())` then call it like this: `SATURATE_ADD(x, 10, 1, 0, foo);`

Comment: (wasn't me). I'm getting an error implicit declaration of func is invalid in C99

Comment: @quantumpotato you have to declare your function if you want to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a function to solve the problem similar to the function in pseudocode

```
void cycle_counter(int *px, char operatorr, int max, int init, void (*p)())
{
   *px=init;

   //in some loop

   operatorr?(*px)++:(*px)--;    //if the operator is 0 we usee -- otherwise ++

   ((*px)>max)?((*px)=0,p()):0; // This line replaces the if statement in your 
                                // code and the callback
}
```

so here we have used the pointer named `px` which is pointing to `x` so it can keep the changes

The operator `operatorr` is a boolean which takes the value **0** for `--` and `++` otherwise

`max` is an integer that will be provided for comparison. In your example it will be **10**

`init` is for the initialisation of the integer pointed by the pointer `px`

Finally `p` refers to a pointer to function

Now if you want to call this function in the main function you will proceed like that

```
 cycle_counter(px, 1, 10, 0, myfunc);
```

with `px` is

```
int x;
int *px=&x;
```

There are some exceptions not treated but I've jsut  tried to make the difficult part which treats the ***pointers to functions***. The other part (not done  > and >=) is easy you can make the ternary operator even more  complicated to handle all the cases but you will probably get a lovely line which can be considered as an **obfuscated** line  ;)